# All Http Request is hitting two times in zuul pre-filter when hitting from postman or browser

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

All  Http  Request  is hitting twice in  zuul pre-filter when hitting from postman or any browser and performing all operation twice.  I searched for this but could not found an answer.

I am not able to add my real implementation here so adding dummy code.
My pre-filter class is:

```
public class ApplicationGateway extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() 
    { 
        LOGGER.debug("PRINT");
        // PRINT is printing two times in each request
    }
}
```

and my Main class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy 
public class 
    Application 
extends 
    SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationGateway preFilter() {
        return new ApplicationGateway();
    }

    @Bean
    public PostFilter postFilter() {
        return new PostFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorFilter errorFilter() {
        return new ErrorFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteFilter routeFilter() {
        return new RouteFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationGateway getAuthenticatedFilter () {
        return new ApplicationGateway();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why are you returning bean of type AplicationGateway from getAuthenticatedFilter, remove that, it should work

Comment: this worked for me, thnx @jayant mishra. sorry i dont have reputation to upvote

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the end code is  ?  the `ApplicationGateway` does not have annotation `@Component` or something. And is there any bean in main class application or its removed at all ?